# Finding a cycle in a graph under constraints

Tags: graph-theory, network-flow

You are given a directed graph $G=(V,E)$ with capacities $c(e) \in R^+$ and a set of edges $E_1 \subset E$.
You want to find a cycle $C = (v_1, v_2), (v_2, v_3) ... (v_n, v_1)$ in the graph under the constraint that the capacity of the cycle is not bottlenecked exclusively by an edge $e \in E_1$ or $\exists e \in C, e \notin E_1 \: c(e) = \min\limits_{e_1 \in C} c(e_1)$

I know finding a cycle without constraints is easy using DFS search. My question is can the method be extended to solve the constrained problem while maintaining good performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a polynomial algorithm (which can probably be improved):
For each $e=(u,v) \notin E_1$, take the graph $G\setminus \{e'\in E,c(e') < c(e)\}$ and find if there is a path from $v$ to $u$. If such a cycle exists, it will be found when testing the edge $e$ minimizing $c$ in the cycle.

**Edit:**
Here is a more efficient algorithm. Compute the all-pairs shortest path on the graph, with maximization of the bottleneck as the distance. This can be done using Floyd-Warshall, by replacing addition with a min, and instead of choosing the minimum value between the two possibilities, you take the max. Then for each edge $e=(u,v)\notin E_1$, you check if there is a path from $v$ to $u$ with a bottleneck greater than $c(e)$. This is $|V|^3$, compared to the $|E|^2$ given above.

Comment: could one run tarjan algorithm for strongly connected components and remove all vertices not in a component and then pick the edge with lowest capacity if it was not $(u,v) \in E_1$ and then run shortest path with that $v \rightarrow u$. if the lowest capacity edge was in $E_1$ remove it and run tarjan again ...

Would this work better? in what situations?

Comment: It should work. The worst case complexity seems to be $|E|^2$ (attained if every edge is in $E_1$ and you start from the complete graph). It will probably be better in case the graph have small strongly connected components, but I'm sure there is a better algorithm than the one I gave. Don't have much time for the moment, but I will try to look at it later.

Comment: I do not checked it carefully but maybe you can compute strongly connected components on $G\setminus E_1$, then for each edge from $E \setminus E_1$ from highest cost to lowest, add edges from $E_1$ with higher cost while maintaining iteratively the strongly connected components. The whole cost for maintaining the connected components is $\mathcal{O}(|V|^2log(|V|)$ I think, using incremental cycle detection. You also have a ($\mathcal{O}(|E|log(|E|))$ if we need to sort costs on edges)

Comment: I forgot to specify that you find a cycle whenever the edge you are considering belongs to a strongly connected component.